# Django: Object is not iterable when trying to instantiate an object

Tags: python, django

I am getting 'Players' object is not iterable when I am trying to save some form data, and I don't understand why.

Here is my RequestedPartners model:

```
class RequestedPartners(models.Model):
    first_nm = models.CharField('Requested Partner First Name', max_length=100)
    last_nm = models.CharField('Requested Partner Last Name', max_length=100)
    player = models.ManyToManyField(Players)
```

Here is my form:

```
class RequestedPartnersForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = RequestedPartners
        fields = ['first_nm', 'last_nm']

    def clean_first_nm(self):
        return self.cleaned_data['first_nm'].upper()

    def clean_last_nm(self):
        return self.cleaned_data['last_nm'].upper()
```

Here is the Players model:

```
class Players(models.Model):
    first_nm = models.CharField('First Name', max_length=100)
    last_nm = models.CharField('Last Name', max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField('Email Address (optional)', max_length=200, null=True)
```

Here is my view method where I'm getting the "'Players' object is not iterable" error.

```
def post(self, request):
    bound_form = UsersForm(request.POST)
    lineItemsForm = LineItemsForm(request.POST)
    RequestedPartnersFormSet = formset_factory(RequestedPartnersForm)
    formset = RequestedPartnersFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)

    if bound_form.is_valid() and lineItemsForm.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
        bound_form.save()
        players = Players()
        players.first_nm = bound_form.cleaned_data['first_nm']
        players.last_nm = bound_form.cleaned_data['last_nm']
        players.email = bound_form.cleaned_data['email']
        players.save()

        for form in formset.cleaned_data:
            rp1 = RequestedPartners()
            rp1.last_nm = form['last_nm']
            rp1.first_nm = form['first_nm']
            rp1.player = players # Error is being thrown on this line
            rp1.save()

        return redirect(reverse('begin_registration'))
```

What am I doing wrong that is causing this error?

Comment: Can you add the traceback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RequestedPartners.player` is a ManyToManyField. As per the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) they have a special api when you need to assign values to them.

First, you need to save the `RequestedPartners` object (so that it has a primary key) then add the players:

```
rp1 = RequestedPartners()
rp1.last_nm = form['last_nm']
rp1.first_nm = form['first_nm']
rp1.save()
rp1.player.add(players)
rp1.save()
```

Comment: Nailed it. Thanks very much. I'm trying to learn python/django while building a website, and there is a lot to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Attribute player is ManyToMany declaration. You can't assign value like that, try this instead

```
rp1.player.add(players)
```

Comment: Thank you. I wondered if I was doing something wrong with that assignment.